Can the Bundestag (German federal diet) initiate new elections?
On 2024-11-06, German chancellor Olaf Scholz fired finance minister Christian Lindner, leader of the junior coalition party FDP, thereby ending the majority coalition between SPD, Bündnis 90/Die Grünen, and FDP.  He announced asking the Bundestag (federal diet) for a vote of confidence (Vertrauensfrage) in January to prepare for elections in March.  Opposition politicians have criticised this as too late, stating this question should be asked immediately to prepare for elections in January.
Couldn't the Bundestag take the initiative for such a vote, or do they need to wait for the chancellor to do so?  Considering parliamentary sovereignty (bounded by the constitution / constitutional court), I would expect that a majority of parliament can "send home" a government (or individual ministers) at any time.  It seems strange to me that a government that has lost its parliamentary majority could stay in power until the next regularly scheduled elections (despite having difficulties passing legislation as a minority government), as long as they don't ask parliament if they still trust the government.

It can only elect a new Chancellor. See Vote of no confidence, article 67 of the constituion.

"It seems strange to me that a government that has lost its parliamentary majority could stay in power until the next regularly scheduled elections..." Why is this strange? It would be a minority government. That exists in many countries.

@NoDataDumpNoContribution Parliament has the supreme power, which should mean that parliament can send home a government (minority or not) at any time, such as is the case in The Netherlands.  Parliament is "the boss" and should have the power to fire government ministers or the entire government.

@gerrit They don’t just have to fire the current government, they have to provide a better one. Even if not by law then in the eyes of the people. Just because a majority is against the current government doesn’t mean there is a majority for a hypothetical next government.

The newspaper Die Zeit had an article in German that explains the procedure that is going to happen now: https://www.zeit.de/politik/deutschland/2024-11/bundesregierung-weg-zur-neuwahl-vertrauensfrage-faq

@MisterMiyagi That sounds like an answer (if you have sources).  When the chancellor loses a vote of confidence, new elections are triggered.  Apparently, Germany does not allow parliament to initiate such a vote of confidence themselves (and trigger new elections).

@gerrit It’s not an answer to what you asked in the question.

@gerrit "...which should mean that parliament can send home a government (minority or not) at any time..." And then the country has no government at all? In all these cases the previous government will remain in place until a new on is chosen, so not much change to the status quo. Why should Parliaments have a right to decide the date of new elections? This would be rather surprising for me and I would guess it could easily be exploited.

@NoDataDumpNoContribution I would expect that the "sacked" government would remain until a new one is in place.  That's how it works in The Netherlands.  The difference is that Parliament decides on new elections and not the government.

A note on parliamentary sovereignty: The Bundestag is not sovereign but part of a system of checks and balances which includes many different actors. In that sense, Germany is closer to the US than to the UK.

@gerrit "Parliament decides on new elections" they don't need to. They can directly elect a new government any time they want to. Why would they want then new elections effectively shortening the election cycle?

Scholz is not planing on staying until the next scheduled election, he's planning on bringing it forward to March

@JackAidley I know.  But as far as I understand it, he could stay until the next regularly scheduled elections and not ask the Vertrauensfrage at all, and will be able to do so unless the Bundestag finds a majority to replace him.

@MisterMiyagi in the Netherlands, when the cabinet falls, that cabinet will then remain in power (with on paper reduced powers and responsibilities but in practice that part is often forgotten) until new elections are held and a new cabinet is formed, which can take months, in extreme cases more than a year. Which is what happened in the Netherlands last year in fact, the (on paper) deposed cabinet went on ruling like nothing had happened and even bragged about being able to do whatever they wanted as they could no longer be sent home.

@jwenting I believe that theoretically, Dutch parliament can properly send home any ministers (including the PM) from a caretaker cabinet, but will not do so as then there would be an actual vacancy.  I'm not sure if this has happened, but I seem to recall this option being discussed for individual ministers misbehaving in a caretaker government, who were then replaced before parliament could take action.

The first time I have seen this meaning of diet.

The aim of the German Basic Law is to ensure a viable and stable government. As such, it actively blocks the willfull deselection of the Chancellor, unless he is replaced with a successor, and the willfull dissolution of parliament, unless the viability of the government is demonstratably impaired. Only the Chancellor is given the right to make that call, and he has to prove it via loosing a vote of confidence, and the Federal President has the right to not dissolve it even then.
In a 2005 decision (German text), the Federal Constitutional Court had to decide whether a vote of confidence called by Chancellor Schröder was constitutional.
The decision recounts the historical insights that lead to this design, if you are interested. For this answer, the general remarks on the nature of a "political crisis", and the "escape routes" the constitution offers, may suffice:

The Basic Law seeks to create a viable government by means of Article 63, Article 67 and Article 68. Viability means not only that the Federal Chancellor exercises political will in order to determine the general guidelines of policy, and that he bears responsibility for this (Article 65.1 of the Basic Law), but is also aware of having a majority of Members of the German Bundestag behind him in so doing (1.). The Basic Law contains special provisions in order to keep a minority government viable in a political crisis if necessary. Primarily, however, it offers escape routes aiming to restore stable majorities in the German Bundestag (2.)...
(1.) The constitution aims to create a government anchored in Parliament. The Federal Chancellor is elected by the Bundestag (Article 63 of the Basic Law). In order to effectively implement his mandate to shape policy thereby allotted, he requires the continuous support of the majority of the German Bundestag...
The Federal Chancellor and his Government need in principle a reliable parliamentary majority. Reliable means in this context that the Chancellor may anticipate fundamental, adequate parliamentary support for the political concept he represents...
(2.) If the Federal Chancellor is not (any longer) able to assemble the majority of Members of the Bundestag around himself, his position is categorised by the Basic Law as a political crisis and is covered by special provisions which also involve other constitutional bodies in the responsibility for dealing with it (Article 63.4 sentence 3 and Article 81 of the Basic Law; see also Article 111 of the Basic Law)...
However, these are only security measures. In principle, the Basic Law has available such ways out of a parliamentary crisis aiming to restore the majorities in the German Bundestag . These escape routes are the resignation and re-election of a Chancellor in accordance with Article 63 of the Basic Law, the election of a new, different chancellor by means of a constructive vote of no confidence in accordance with Article 67 of the Basic Law, and the vote of confidence in the Chancellor in accordance with Article 68 of the Basic Law...By its systematic connection with Article 62 and Article 67 of the Basic Law, Article 68 of the Basic Law however does not afford the Federal Chancellor any means to set a re-election date seeming suitable to him in a manner not subject to preconditions, together with a parliamentary majority reliably supporting him (BVerfGE 62, 1 (42-43)).


To clarify for other readers: "The basic law" is the translation for "das Grundgesetz", the german constitution (some semantic discussions debate whether it can be called that, but it works as such)

@Syndic This is the official translation published by the court on its own website.

To emphasize the core here: (1) Neither the parliament nor the Chancellor nor the President can directly dissolve the parliament and/or initiate new elections. (2) The only procedure to initiate new elections is: The chancellor asks for a vote of confidence in parliament; only when that is denied can the Chancellor ask the President to dissolve the parliament; and the President can or cannot dissolve the parliament and thus initiate new elections.

The tool for this is the "konstruktive Misstrauensvotum" (constructive vote of no confidence). The issue there is that Bundestag would need to elect a new chancellor (that's the "constructive" part). §67 of the Basic Law says that there is no other approach.
I believe, they could just elect someone, who then initiates new elections. But that would generally require an agreement by all opposition parties and sufficient trust. Since CDU/CSU doesn't cooperate with The Left or AFD, they don't have enough votes for this.
Reference (in German):
https://www.bundestag.de/services/glossar/glossar/K/konst_misstrau-245482

"they could just elect someone, who then initiates new elections": No. The only way to dissolve the parliament is through §68, by the chancellor asking for a vote of confidence, and loosing it. If your scenario is, first elect a new chancellor, then he immediately asks for a vote of confidence just to puposefully loose it, that is just absurd.

@ccprog It being absurd doesn't mean it can't happen. There have been highjinx before, like having a vote of no confidence although the government had a clear and stable majority.

Absurdity just means: why elect a new chancellor for the sole purpose of a vote of confidence when the old one has already announced he will pose it himself?

@ccprog The current controversy is that having it in january is too late. Also, the question is not specific to the current situation.

In this case, note the BerfG in its 2005 decision says: "Die auf Auflösung des Bundestages gerichtete Vertrauensfrage ist nur dann verfassungsgemäß, wenn sie nicht nur den formellen Anforderungen, sondern auch dem Zweck des Art. 68 GG entspricht...Die auf Auflösung gerichtete Vertrauensfrage ist als eine dem Zweck des Art. 68 GG entsprechende Maßnahme gerechtfertigt, wenn sie der Wiederherstellung einer ausreichend parlamentarisch verankerten Bundesregierung dient." It would be interesting to see what it would decide in in such a scenario.

In October 1982, Kohl came to power using a "konstruktives Misstrauensvotum) and in December he lost a "Vertrauensfrage", so under some circumstances it is possible for the new chancellor to very quickly move for new elections. It is a controversial decision that may be deemed unconstitutional (although in 1982, the president decided to follow the chancellor's suggestion and the constitutional court decided that it was OK under the circumstances present).

I wonder what would happen, if the Bundestag elected a new Chancellor for the sole purpose of calling a vote of confidence and requesting dissolution of parliament. It runs counter to the ideas behind the constitution (which explicitly does not provide for the Bundestag to remove the government while dissolving itself) but both steps in isolation appear to be legally fine.

@xyldke: As quoted in ccprog's comment, the Supreme Court has already left the door open for themselves in the 2005 decision where they said that a vote of confidence for the sole purpose of dissolving the Bundestag is only constitutional if it not only fulfills the formal requirements but also the goals of Art. 68. In other words, not only the letter but the spirit of the law. They also explained what that means, namely the goal of Art. 68 is the "restoration of a federal government with adequate parliamentary support". So, the question would be whether that is the case or not. But by …

… explicitly calling it out in their 2005 decision, they have already sent a signal that they are willing to declare any abuse unconstitutional, and they have laid out the framework for what they consider acceptable and not.

@JörgWMittag it would be interesting to see that actually ruled on - if someone were to get elected Chancellor now only to immediately call a vote of confidence (expecting new elections), it could be argued that the current government obviously does not have adequate parliamentary support, and new elections are the (best/only) way towards getting a new government with such support. So it might follow the spirit of Art. 68

No, the tool is the Vertrauensfrage (vote of confidence) which the chancellor asks of the parliament. It is irrelevant how that Chancellor got elected (regularly at the beginning of the legislative term or some time during that term, through a "constructive vote of no confidence"). of course you can have all kinds of political scheming but this is the technical answer.

@Peter-ReinstateMonica Bundestag can’t initiate that, which means it’s not the answer to the question at hand.

@Roland of course it is: The answer to "Can the Bundestag initiate new elections?" is "Not directly", and if one wants to elaborate on that, the answer is "it can deny a vote of confidence but that vote can only be triggered by the chancellor, and even then it is the Chancellor who initiates the dissolution, and then it is the prerogative of the President to actually dissolve it, or not. So, indeed, "no, the tool is the Vertrauensfrage asked by the Chancellor" -- and not the parliament's Misstrauensvotum -- is the proper answer to the question.
